# Good book on Origin of Life

Tags: evolution, molecular-evolution, book-recommendation, literature

What is a book that goes into reasonable detail (but isn't textbook-level technical) about the origin of earth and in particular the origin of life on earth? Something intended for a broad audience, but that still covers the biology/geology and does not completely gloss over the sicence.

Comment: I think this may be way too broad.  Are you able to narrow down your interests any further?

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend The selfish gene by Richard Dawkins. It is targeted at a scientifically interested audience, but well written and recognized by the scientific community.

http://amzn.com/0199291152

Answer (score 2):

I think [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198607865) (The Story of Life, Southwood) would be just what you are looking for - it was one of my modules during my undergrad in Evolution and I think it touches on the basic geology too. It is quite an easy ready but covers the material pretty well, it also has good reviews on Amazon etc.

Answer (score 0):

This book by Steven Rose is supposed to be an update of the original for a modern audience:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Almost-Like-Whale-Species-Updated/dp/055299958X

Comment: I think you mean Steve Jones. Steven Rose wrote The Chemistry of Life.